# bigqueryoperator is write_truncate 1 transaction or 2 transactions

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am looking to replace a table in a single transaction.  I am using the bigqueryoperator with `write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE'` and my sql is just `select * from my_table`.  I am wondering if this will happen in a single transaction or two seperate transactions? If it is 2 transactions, is there anyway I can replace my bigquery table with `select * from my_table` in a single transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow submit the query using Job API. BigQuery [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job) mention for both `createDisposition` & `writeDisposition`  that

> Each action is atomic and only occurs if BigQuery is able to complete the job successfully. Creation, truncation and append actions occur as one atomic update upon job completion.

A side note `BigQueryOperator` is deprecated. You should use `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`